# Can not login in wordpress due to changed php file

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /nas/content/staging/rcbook/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/templates/Simple/template-functions.php on line 9
```

I realized woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips plugin does not support Chinese. In other words, invoice will print `??` if it encounters Chinese. I tried to fix it by adding some code on `template-functions.php`. I used file manager Wordpress plugin to access `template-functions.php` and change some code. But it seems like I made some mistakes. Wordpress just does not allow me to login, and I cannot correct my error.

Comment: When you edit PHP files from the Appearance > Editor area of the website, it (as of recently in 4.9) gives you a warning that it's a dangerous practice. You should be editing PHP files via FTP so you can easily address errors like this, otherwise a simple syntax error can lock you out of your site entirely.

Comment: Share that code here so we can let you know

Answer (score 3):

You could try and access/edit **template-functions.php** file from an ftp client.

Comment: I download FileZilla try to connect wordpress. In site manage, i click logon type normal. User:wordpress username password : wordpress password but it can not connect to the server

Answer (score 0):

To regain wp-admin access, you'll have to use FTP or a hosting filemanager.

Go to `yoursite.com/wp-content/plugins/`

Rename the WOO PDF invoice plugin, for example add '-off' to it.

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips-off
```

WP will deactivate the plugin, and you can access the admin again.

BUT.. Like Xhynk said, this is not the way to edit PHP!
Use FTP and a code editor, I use Atom (its free).

1 more thing, i have experience with that plugin. If you edit the 'Simple' template directly, the changes you make, can be overwritten when you update the plugin. This plugins supports the creation of your own template, copy the 'Simple' template and set it to fit your needs.

Follow the instructions [here](https://docs.wpovernight.com/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/creating-a-custom-pdf-template/)

Comment: Thanks, i did for that. the story is like this. the woocommerce invoice does not accept Chinese. i use booster to fix font family like Chinese but it not work. then i go to website you as your instructions creating a new template . but when i visit my invoice realize it still use the old one not the one i created in my personal template. Then, i just try to add my code directly in plugin,,,,,by the way, do you know how to fix invoice no Chinese problem? thanks

Comment: First, dont use WP login and pass for FTP access, they are not the same. Check your hoster info for howto FTP access. Don't you have a hosting control panel you can login to? Most hosting platforms (cPanel,plesk, directadmin, ) all have a filemanager you can use to change files. When you duplicate the Simple template, you have to activate it in the plugin settings page. For chinese font problem, check [this](https://docs.wpovernight.com/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/using-custom-fonts/) . Good luck :-) !